# Symfony clearing cache and dumping assets for all environments?

Tags: php, symfony

I know I can dump assets and clear cache per environment:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

But is there a way to clear cache for *all* environments? And the same question for assetic dumping and all commands that have that environment option.

Comment: I would create a custom task; combine them and run with a single command

Comment: `rm -rf app/cache/*` as for cache clearing. For others - yes, create your own command

Comment: I prefer not typing `rm -rf`'s with long paths because I've once mistakenly had an extra space in the path that caused plenty of content to be removed. I only `rm -rf` at the current directory, in which case I would have to traverse to the cache directory which becomes painful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like [Fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/), [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) or [Capifony](https://everzet.github.io/capifony/) to automate the process.

Comment: **Fabric** - broken link